# Excel display different list based on a selection

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula

I looked in various questions listed here on stack.  I did not see one for creating a second drop down list based off a selection from another drop down list.

List one has three different selections: Report, Ticket, Call
When a user selects one of the three a new drop down list based on the selection will appear in a new cell in the same sheet.

I have the first list working fine.  I thought an if statement would be the direction that I need to go for the second drop down but not sure how it will reference a list or multiple list.

something like this

=IF(B14=Report, SHOW REPORT DROP DOWN, IF(B14=Call, SHOW CALL DROP DOWN, IF(B14=Ticket, SHOW TICKET DROP DOWN, "")))

Please advise

Comment: A google search `site:=http://stackoverflow.com/ dependent drop down list excel` returns "About 4,150 results", but I think this site explains it well:  http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0):

Say we want the *DV* list in cell **A2** to depend on the selection from the *DV* list in **A1**:

[image]

So if we pick *fruit* in **A1**, the fruit list should be the *DV* list for **A2**

In the *DV* setup for **A2**, use this formula:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,IF(A1="dog",D1:D4,E1:E4))
```

[image]